# Quiz Game / Clicking a button to add text to label

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Im making a quiz. And it works like this, When you are answearing a question, you have to click some buttons with text on them to answear.

Example () = button

(G) (L) (O) (R) (I) (O) (U) (S)

And they have to spell glorious in that label correctly. And when they click the answear button, if the label says Glorious, they go to the next level. And if it says something else like Gloirous a message saying wrong answear will come up.

The problem :

The problem is that when i click a button, it adds text to the label.

But when i click another button the previous text dissapears and the new comes in.

I hope you guys understand what i want here! My english is not the best but if you want me to post some code i can do that !;)

Comment: Down voter please give a reason?:) Or are you just doing it to feel better?:) Feel sorry for you if so :(

Comment: I think you are getting downvoted because you provide no code

Comment: This is a low-quality question, but I agree with the OP that "drive-by" down voting is rude and annoying. To the OP, if you're going to ask a "why isn't my code working" type question, you need to provide the code that you're struggling with. You should show your instance variables, as well as your action methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save previous text, and append new text to previous.

```
label.setText(label.text() + newText)
```

Comment: The OP has Objective-C and C++ tags in their question (but not Swift). Swift is going to confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[yourLabel setText:[yourLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"%@", yourButton.text]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the text to a label. Display the text in a label, but store it somewhere else.

Create an instance variable "answerString". Append each letter to the answer string, and then display the answer string to your label:

```
NSString *answerString;
```

Also, don't write a different IBAction method for each button. Put numeric tags on each button, attach them to the same method, and use the tag number to figure out which button was pressed. Something like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, buttonTags)
{
 aButton = 100,
 bButton = 101,
 cButton = 102
//and so on for the entire alphabet, or for the letters you need
}

- (IBAction) buttonAction: (UIButton *) sender;
{
  int button_id = sender.tag;
  switch (button_id)
  {
    case aButton:
      answerString = [answerString stringByAppendingString: @"a"];
      break;
    case bButton:
      answerString = [answerString stringByAppendingString: @"b"];
      break;
  }
  answerLabel.text = answerString
}
```

If you have buttons for all 26 letters it probably makes more sense to do some math on the tag numbers to get the unicode value of each character rather than having a switch statement with 26 cases, but you get the idea.